# SQL Server Decimals have changed

Tags: sql, ms-access, import

I have jusrt uploaded an Access Database to SQL Server 2008 and the numeric fields have been changed to things like:

2.5364E-05, 
2.5364E-05, 
2.7598E-05, 
2.8425E-05, 
2.7598E-05, 
2.5364E-05, 
2.5364E-05,

I have seen this happen before, but now i need to know how to resolve it.

Is there any way to convert the numbers back, or avoid the problem in the first place?

Thanks all!

C

Comment: Where are you seeing those values? Is that simply how they are being displayed or are they strings in the SQL database (and if so, why are they set up as strings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **very** unlikely that your data has actually been changed. This is a presentational effect that happens with the decimal data type.

Have you tried formatting the data using `CONVERT(VarChar, ...)`? What is the format you're expecting?